# C# Read Summary Function

Tags: c#, reflection, summary

there is a way to read the summary of function automatically from another CS file?
I explain - I have the method

```
void foo(int x);
```

with Reflection I read the function name and his parameters but I also need to read his summary. The summary is XML style.

Thanks.

Comment: This question is pretty unclear.

Comment: Do you know that XML docs can be generated at build time?

Comment: That information is not available via reflection. It's not compiled into the dll.

Answer (score 0):

Generate a documentation XML file by checking the checkbox option in the build tab of the properties of your project and build it.

If you refer to the assembly, the documentation will be loaded automatically.

Also, the XML contains simple raw data from the xml comments.

For this function to work you'll need to use the XML /// comment style like this:

```
/// <summary>
/// Class description
/// </summary>
public class Foo
{
   /// <summary>
   /// Constructor description
   /// </summary>
   void Foo()
   {
   }
}
```

Other than in the XML or .cs files this info is not available.

[image]

Comment: its create one XML file for all the class in the same project?

Comment: I thought it's one for each assembly.